# UITextView make keyboard permanent?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uikeyboard

I have two `UITextViews` in one UI, One of the `UITextView` is the first responder. The other `UITextView` is non-editable. When I double tap the non-editable `UITextView`, the keyboard disappears and I want to avoid this. They keyboard should always stay.

Comment: If u ddn't want anything happened on second textview then set it's userInteraction disable.

Comment: hmm why not use UILabel instead of (2nd) UITextView if it's not editable? (Just wondering)

Comment: 1. Because multiline text appears vertically centered in a UILabel. 2. UILabels can't scroll. 3. Making dynamic text with multiple lines look good on UILabel is complicated.

Comment: Yes, that's why I am not using the UILabel. The correct solution is provided by @MatthiasBauch but I wanted the UIMenuController option to still show up.

Comment: @NoorSyed Please mark any of the answers as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

If you double tap on a text view, it shows UIMenuController with Cut, Copy, etc options.

So to achieve your requirement, set User Interaction property to NO (False).

Hope this is what you are looking for.

-Mrunal

Comment: If you have setUserInteractionEnabled:NO or the solution which @Matthias shared, it doesn't show cut copy paste etc

Answer (score 1):

Make your viewController the delegate of the textView and return `NO` from the [UITextViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html) method `textViewShouldEndEditing:`

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    if (textView == self.editableTextView) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Your solution works but I still wanted the cut copy paste menu controller. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this is not default behavior. to achieve your requirement try this using delagate method `shouldChangeTextInRange` and make your textview editable

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //nonEditingTextView.editable = NO; 
    //make the nonEditingTextView editable
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if ( textView == nonEditingTextView ) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Firstly add the below code for keyboard notification into your viewdidload method.

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keybordWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keybordWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

//Let the two textview's names be, NonEditable and Editable

//declare a flag globally
bool Appearflag;

//Then implement the two methods as follows

-(void)keybordWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification

{

    if ([NonEditable isFirstResponder] && Appearflag)
    {
        [Editable becomeFirstResponder];
    }else if ([Editable isFirstResponder])
    {
        Appearflag = NO;
    }
}

-(void)keybordWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification

{

    if ([Editable isFirstResponder])
    {
        Appearflag = YES;
    }
}
```